# Slide right to left transition anim. Fragment -> Activity

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-activity, transition

I have a fragment with list view on it. When the user clicks on any of the list view's items he/she is transferred in an Activity. The default animation of the activity that is started (startActivity from the fragment -> opens this activity) is from the bottom slide to top of the screen. How I can override this animation and create a slide from right animation when the activity is created.

I have tried to override the overridePendingTransition method in the activity but that did not change anything.

```
@Override
public void overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim) {
    super.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Dat paint skillz tho :D

Comment: @adelphus Thank you  for your suggestion but the problem is that Fragment does not have such method.

Comment: No, the *Activity* owning the fragment does. Since the transition is at the Activity level, that's where you need to modify the transition.

Comment: @adelphus hmm, make sense. Will try that now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @adelphus Yes, it worked! Thanks! Could you add your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev @adelphus Wait what? I'm facing exactly the same issue myself, but I don't get how you've fixed this. I thought you wanted the effect to take place from when the user goes from a `Fragment` to an `Activity`, yet you declared the effect in `Activity`? How does that make sense...?

Comment: @adelphus Tbh it&#39;s been a while and I don&#39;t remember what I did nor I have the source code anymore. Sorry that I can&#39;t help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Activity.overridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) documentation :

*Call immediately after one of the flavors of startActivity(Intent) or finish() to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.*

In other words, call the method on the current Activity after starting the new Activity, instead of overriding it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Facing the exact same problem. I've made an Intent in my Fragment to open a new Activity from, and after `startActivity(intent)` I put `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);` and then get the "cannot resolve method" error.